Todo list app with a feature to move tasks up and down
Recommend me a desktop TODO program (for Linux or Windows or cross-platform like Java or .Net app), preferably an editor for todo.txt file format, where you can set priority for a task, and move tasks up and down in the list (inside the same priority), in other words, to set an exact order of tasks.

Community Apps: Todo.txt on your favorite device or platform

@Blindspots, which of these programs has this feature? I used jdotxt and QTodoTxt2 and none of them has it.

todo.txt files will always be sorted in the same "exact order" (dictionary sort) as described in the standard: "todo.txt format".

note app "mynotex" allows reordering items using up/down arrows to anything you want.  Could make a subject (really a notebook) and move the embedded notes (could be your todo tasks) to the order you wish.

@Blindspots, in jdotxt inside the same priority they are sorted in the order I added them.

@tckosvic, it's not a todo list app

@havon it is a dictionary sort by design so the creation date (if exists) would be the next sort index after Priority, or first if there's no priority.

@Blindspots, it'll be ok to use another file format. "Preferably", but not "mandatory".

I looked at Markor (Android) and it supported various sorts in addition to dictionary (see image) you can also move tasks up and down. I imagine that this should be avail in one of the other non-Android apps.
